# find indices in array, use indices as lookup, plot w/r/t time

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm looking to find the n largest values in an array, then to use the indices of those found values as a *look up* into another array representing time.  But I am wondering how I can plot this if i want time to display as a continuous variable.  Do I need to zero out data?  That wouldn't be preferable for my use case as I'm looking to save memory.

Let's say that I have array A, which is where I am looking for the max values.  Then I have array T, which represents timestamps.  I want my plot to display continuous time and plot() doesn't like arguments of differing size.  How do most people deal with this?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
numtofind = 4;
A = m{:,10};
T = ((m{:,4} *  3600.0) + (m{:,5} * 60.0) + m{:,6});

[sorted, sortindex] = sort(A(:), 'descend');
maxvalues = sorted(1:numtofind);
maxindex = sortindex(1:numtofind);
corresponding_timestamps = T(maxindex);

%here i plot the max values against time/corresponding timestamps, 
%but i want to place them in the right timestamp and display time as continuous 
%rather than the filtered set:
plot(time_values, maxvalues);
```

Comment: I saw this reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/time-series-tools.html#brenq06-24, but I am not able to access this tool set as I am programming this in octave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "time as continuous", do you mean you want time going from minimum to maximum? If so, you can just sort `corresponding_timestamps` and use that to reorder `maxvalues`. Even if you don't do that, you can still do `plot(time_values, maxvalues, '.')` to get a scatter plot which won't mess up your graph with lines.

Comment: That is not exactly what I meant, but I'm marking it correct, because I can't find another solution.